# Unable to access wamp server using public IP: Webpage unavailable

Tags: wamp

I have trying to connect my phone with the wampserver I created and trying to use different networks for both PC and mobile. To enable port forwarding I have changed the port in httpd.conf to

> Listen 8080

and in my router settings I have added separate entries: one for TCP and one for UDP packets.

[image: IP/Port Forwarding in Router]

Lastly, I have also enabled

> #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
>
> > ```
> > Require all granted
> > ```

in the httpd.conf file as well. Technically, I should be able to access my wampserver by

> http://{public IP address}:{8080}/

I have also given access to the port 8080 in my firewall, but when I check it online with my public if, I get the 8080 port is closed on the {public IP address}. Unfortunately, I am not able to access the following server. I am bit confused at the moment and I guess I am stuck with something really silly. I will be deeply obliged if anyone could help me with the issue.

Comment: Before working on the external access, make sure it works internally. From another machine on the same LAN segment, try going to http://{private IP address}:8080/ such as `http://192.168.1.45:8080`. Once that works, you can move ahead with troubleshooting the external connection.

Comment: Also, since this is about a networking problem rather than a programming problem, it's likely off topic and probably belongs on Super User or Server Fault instead.

Comment: Is this different from your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934796/wamp-server-is-unable-to-access-using-public-ip-address ?