# Wamp server is unable to access using public ip address

Tags: networking, routes, wamp

I have trying to connect my phone with the wampserver I created and is looking forward for an OTP based application. I aim to have a different network for both the PC and mobile and look forward to use public IP for accessing. To enable port forwarding I have changed the port in httpd.conf to

> Listen 8080

and in my router settings I have added separate entries: one for TCP and one for UDP packets.

[image: IP/Port Forwarding in Router]

Lastly, I have also enabled

> #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
>
> > ```
> > Require all granted
> > ```

in the httpd.conf file as well. Technically, I should be able to access my wampserver by

> http://{public IP address}:{8080}/

I have also given access to the port 8080 in my firewall, but when I do check online the status of port in public IP, it shows **8080 port is closed on the {public IP address**}. Unfortunately, I am not able to access the following server. I am bit confused at the moment and I guess I am stuck with something really silly. I will be deeply obliged if anyone could help me with the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access wamp server using public IP: Webpage unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915772/unable-to-access-wamp-server-using-public-ip-webpage-unavailable)

Answer (score 1):

If your port is still closed / blocked you probably have another router / firewal / ... blocking it. Does your internt providor maybe have a router of their own in front of your router?

Comment: I have been using an Internet Dongle provided by one of the telecom company. I had following setting in the firewall of dongle including Port filtering,port forwarding, UPnP & DMZ. Although, i dont have much idea about another router in front of it .

Comment: So the dongle gives you mobile internet? Like 3G or 4G? Or it's connected to a wireless network in your house?

Comment: Yeah. It gives me mobile internet like 3G or 4G. Its directly connected to my pc not with the wireless network.

Comment: Is your pc IP-address 192.168.0.100 ? Is your phone on the same network as your PC? Because if it is, then regardless of your port being open or closed you should be able to connect to it by using local ip address and port.

Comment: Yes, thats my private ip. The thing is I want to have access to the server even while my phone has different network. Ultimately, I want to host the wamp server I created online, so that I can access the same server with the public ip and port.

Comment: I guess the reason is that the port is not opening. Can u suggest ways by which I can ensure that the following port is open?

Comment: Well you need to make sure that every device between your computer and your 'internet' has that port set open. So which devices exactly are that? Only the dongle?

Comment: Yes. Its only the dongle. In the dongle I have enabled the port forwarding for the TCP/UDP for the Port range 8080-8080, I have added the image of the port forwarding settings in the question above. Also I have enabled the  DMZ settings. Nevertheless, I have even tried switching off the firewall for the PC. Yet, the port remains closed.

Comment: Ok and just to make sure you have set your pc ip address to static 192.168.0.100 ?

Comment: The thing is whenever I have changed the ip address to static 192.168.0.100, the internet stops working.

Comment: Your default gateway will probably be 192.168.0.1, DNS server you can use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 These are the google DNS Servers. And subnetmask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: Yes. I have changed everything as you recommended.

Comment: And are you still connected to the internet?

Comment: Yeah. Internet works fine now but the port remains still closed.

Comment: Ok check 2 things, start a cmd prompt window and try 'ipconfig' .. At the network adapter which you are using you should see your ip address, does it say 192.168.0.100 ? After that type 'netstat -a', it will show you a list with ports. Is port 8080 in it? And does it say listening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105985/discussion-between-matthias-and-thomas-k).